# Google Glass: Starting an activity with "Ok Glass, Command"

Tags: android, voice, google-glass

Using this code snippet, as directed by Google's guide, presents an additional voice input screen.

```
<activity
    android:name="ca.lvin.myfirstglassapp.MyPuppiesSlideshowActivity "
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
        android:resource="@xml/my_voice_trigger" />
</activity>
```

What I want:

1. "Ok, Glass"
2. "Show me the pictures of puppies" (As per https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/theme-widgets)
3. MyPuppiesSlideshowActivity launches

What I'm getting:

1. "Ok, Glass"
2. "Show me the pictures of puppies"
3. **Microphone asking for more input is presented**
4. **Say anything to the mic screen**
5. MyPuppiesSlideshowActivity launches

Can someone help me get rid of the two extra steps?

Related to this: [Voice command for apps in Google Glass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087986/voice-command-for-apps-in-google-glass) but I couldn't comment on the original thread due to the lack of reputation...

---

Resolved!
I copied the code from this site verbatim
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice

```
<trigger keyword="@string/glass_voice_trigger">
    <input prompt="@string/glass_voice_prompt" />
</trigger>
```

And the input tag was the problem. Removing it took care of the prompt.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the contents of "my_voice_trigger.xml"?

Comment: Hi I have created a sample application just like that. Its working, Please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure without seeing your voice trigger XML, but it sounds like you might have written the trigger to expect additional input by including this line:

```
<input prompt="@string/glass_voice_prompt" />
```

Remove that line from your trigger and it won't prompt you.