# Why is my voice command missing from the ok glass menu in XE16?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I had a Glassware that launched using a voice command on the ok glass menu. It worked great in XE12, but in XE16 it does not show up in the main menu.

Here's a snippet from my `AndroidManifest.xml` showing my voice command configuration:

```xml
<service
    android:name="com.mimming.sugarglider.MapDisplayService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
        android:resource="@xml/show_map" />
</service>
```

And here's the contents of `show_map.xml`, which defines my voice command:

```xml
<trigger keyword="@string/show_me_a_map">
    <constraints network="true" />
</trigger>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Answering my own question, since this seems to be impacting a lot of developers.

Voice commands changed a bit in XE16. [Unlisted voice commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware#unlisted_commands), like the one specified in your configuration, now require an additional permission. Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

When you're ready to release your Glassware, you must use a built-in static voice command. XML for this kind of command would look more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger command="START_A_RUN" />
```

Where `START_A_RUN` is one of the items from [this list](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command). If none of the listed commands are appropriate for your Glassware, you should [request the addition of a voice command](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form). This can take some time, so it's best to do this as early as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jenny for sharing. Any idea about TimeLineManager Class ? Its deprecated in XE16. What's its replacement ?

Comment: @Steve that sounds like it might warrant a new question :)

Comment: they have updated lots of functionalities and method names etc.