# With new KitKat Glass version my Glass app I developed under API 15 stopped working

Tags: google-glass

With new KitKat Glass version my Glass app I developed under API 15 stopped working.  I updated the syntax of all calls and I can install the .apk on my Glass hardware, but I can't trigger the voice command to launch my Glass immersion.

How do you debug the command not showing up in the menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XE16 the way voice commands works was changed.

See this questions to see how to upgrade XE12->XE16 voice launch feature.

[Why is my voice command missing from the ok glass menu in XE16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097828/why-is-my-voice-command-missing-form-the-ok-glass-menu-in-xe16)