# Application install but not displaying in Google Glass after KitKat Update

Tags: android, google-glass, android-4.4-kitkat

After updating the OS to kitkat 4.4.2 in Glass, the application I am installing using glassware or via usb debugging are not visible in "OK Glass" -> Immersion. Even on the glass time-line the installed app via glassware are shown as facebook 2min ago, twitter 10min ago but when I was trying to access them using "Ok Glass" command they are not visible in the list of apps.

Comment: have you used/insert voice based intent/launcher in the AndroidManifest.xml ??

Comment: yes, the same app is working fine for the previous version i.e. 4.0.4

Comment: Is there any kitkat specific setting for glass ?

Comment: The method to set voice commands changed in XE16. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097828/why-is-my-voice-command-missing-from-the-ok-glass-menu-in-xe16 for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same problem with my GDK app was fixed by adding

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

to the manifest. This is new for XE16, but the change isn't well documented IMHO.