# After Android 4.4 update my immersive app from glass disappeared

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I just updated my google glass to kitkat and then my app disappeared. and even when I am trying to install it on the glass again, its not showing up. no errors in the logcat. I am not sure what is wrong, does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Voice trigger change addressed in this question - "why-is-my-voice-command-missing-from-the-ok-glass-menu-in-xe16" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097828/why-is-my-voice-command-missing-from-the-ok-glass-menu-in-xe16

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for voice trigger was updated in the GDK.

For unlisted voice triggers, you now need to request the `com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT` permission (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware#unlisted_commands).

Comment: That worked!! did they even get rid of TimelineManager?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete it, it's no longer needed in XE16, you can publish your LiveCard directly with the publish method.