# Install google glass app to android mobile

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm developing app for google glass. I don't have glass, so i used to install file to android device. I referred this document  [Installing Google Glass in an Android Phone](http://pathofacoder.com/2013/07/19/installing-google-glass-in-an-android-phone/) . But when i install and open my own custom voice trigger app, it won't open. I didn't see my app in list of voice command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to keep in mind.

First of all, those instructions were for a much older release of the Glass system. There have been many changes in how to launch a GDK app since then, and the most recent have been outlined in [Why is my voice command missing from the ok glass menu in XE16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097828/why-is-my-voice-command-missing-from-the-ok-glass-menu-in-xe16)

Second, it is really difficult to appreciate the differences between Glass and more traditional Android devices. While you can probably get a basic understanding of development for Glass, you may have trouble understanding the UX differences. It is like trying to write for a mobile phone only by using a desktop computer.