# How to find the installed apps in google glass?

Tags: android, sdk, google-glass, google-gdk

I started developing **helloworld sample application for Google glass** and followed all the similar steps as mentioned in the [link](http://wearableappreview.com/install-apk-google-glass/) and builded the application successfully . But unfortunately i couldn't able to find the installed application in the google glass device since i am a newbie to glass development. Kindly help me how to check the list of apps installed in the device. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application wasn't built properly for Glass (With a voice trigger and the development permission needed if using a custom voice trigger) it will install but you won't see it in the list of apps on the device, you can see more info in the link below:

[Why is my voice command missing from the ok glass menu in XE16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097828/why-is-my-voice-command-missing-from-the-ok-glass-menu-in-xe16)

**There is currently no way for a user to view installed apps on Glass except using the main menu (Either by saying "OK Glass" or tapping to see the menu)**

You can launch the activity using:

```
adb am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname
```

You can also try and use [Launchy](https://github.com/kaze0/launchy) by Mike DiGiovanni which allows you to start native apps using the Glass interface

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But normally where can i find my installed apps if the build is completely successful. Whereas in mobile i will find apps in menu option or through shortcut icon. But in google glass i couldn't able to find any menu screens for apps.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include this too, there is no app drawer in Glass as it doesn't sport a full launcher as we know on android, if the app isn't in the menu, the user can't access it.

Comment: Thanks Johnny for your answer. Really it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following intent to manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="com.google.android.glass.category.DIRECTORY"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the XE but in the EE2 you can view installed apps in a standard Android menu by doing the following:

1. Go to settings card
2. Swipe over to device info
3. Tap it 5 times to open the Android settings menu
4. Go to applications from there

The settings menu is really hard to navigate with the glass touch interface so you may want to use some remote interface. I've been using Vysor and I'm sure there are others.