# Hello World in Google Glass

Tags: java, eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

I have problem create a basic applicationn for google glass based on this  [tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/tutorial-83-hello-world-using-google-glass/#respond). I have 2 classes. I followed exactly the same as the tutorial, but I couldn't find it in google glass. I tried from "Ok Glass", but I also couldnt find it.
I have created 2 classes, the first is HelloWorldActivity.java. This class is a  Activity class. Here is the HelloWorldActivity.java

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Card myCard = new Card(this);
    myCard.setText("Hello, World!"); 
    myCard.setFootnote("First Glassware for Glass"); 
    View cardView = myCard.getView();       
    // Display the card we just created
    setContentView(cardView);
}


}
```

The second is HelloGlass.java This class is a Service class that will recognize the voice command.

```
public class HelloGlass extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, HelloWorldActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    return START_STICKY;
   } 
}
```

I have created the necessary xml files including the voice_trigger_start.xml. Here is the andorid manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.helloglass"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:enabled="true" >
            </activity>
             <service
                android:name="com.app.helloglass.HelloGlass"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
                </intent-filter>  
                <!-- Voice command found in res/xml/voice_trigger_start -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                    android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
            </service>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Anybody know what I have missed? I tried to run it but I couldn't find it.

Comment: can you update your question to also show your voice_trigger_start.xml file, please?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

After adding the permission, the voice command works fine but the app crashes because the package name in the manifest is wrong.

[See the whole update project on my GitHub.](https://github.com/prt2121/HelloGlass)

[The tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/tutorial-83-hello-world-using-google-glass) uses a custom voice command. You need this permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

Please see [Why is my voice command missing from the ok glass menu in XE16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097828/why-is-my-voice-command-missing-from-the-ok-glass-menu-in-xe16) and also https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice

Could you try this manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.helloglass"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:enabled="true" >
            </activity>
             <service
                android:name="com.app.helloglass.HelloGlass"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
                </intent-filter>  
                <!-- Voice command found in res/xml/voice_trigger_start -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                    android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
            </service>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, I found the answwer. FIrst of all,there's someonle also create the application for the hello glass (https://github.com/DasCody/Hello-Glass). As I remember, they use the timeLineManager, but because timeLinemanager isn't exist anymore, I have to change it to LiveCard

Comment: Glad you found the answer. If you're still curious what wrong with the tutorial, you can check https://github.com/prt2121/HelloGlass. I just got it working.

Comment: @EntryLevelDev Hi, I hope you don't mind me asking but I'm trying to piece together a Glass project and am an Android novice. We got a few pairs of Glass at work and I'd like to get something up. I'm trying to have a voice trigger start up a menu, ideally "ok glass" styled, and then from any of the choices it would start another activity which is a video player. Could I have some advice on where I'm going wrong? I have panel menu working and videoplayer activity working, but separate from each other and its a bit of a mess now. Any advice is appreciated! https://github.com/tetreault/HelloGlass

Comment: @SMT I will check your issues when I have a chance.

Comment: @EntryLevelDev Hey, I saw what you did on gitr I will take a look soon today. Thank you again for the assistance!